# Optional Randomization of enum variable

Tags: system-verilog, verification, questasim

I am writing a Testbench using Systemverilog and I want to have the freedom to choose in each test to either randomize some variables or specify their value (from a .do file or from command line). Is there any option in Systemverilog to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you can do, but the simplest is putting `+some_variable=value` on the command line, and then in your code

```
if (!$value$plusargs("some_variable=%0d",some_variable)
   some_variable = $urandom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable and use `$urandom` or `$urandom_range` to generate random values. When you want to pass values from the command line, you can use `$value$plusargs`.

Read up on Chapter 21 (Input/output system tasks) of the LRM to find examples.